# Como converter uma string em número no SQLITE 3 ? Exemplo: Como converter 2020/2 em 2020?

Tags: sqlite3

Como converter uma string em número no SQLITE 3  ? Exemplo: Como converter 2020/2 em 2020 de forma que ao usar a condição WHERE periodo < 2014 venha retornar apenas os períodos menores que 2014?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui algo:

```
Select

substr(periodo,1,4)||.0/10 as "periodo_numero"

from TabelaPeriodo
Where periodo_numero < 2014
```